# RAIDs disappearing on reboot (Centos 7.5)

Tags: centos, raid, mdadm, software-raid, dracut

I'm trying to create 4 RAID 0 disk arrays on my system running Centos 7.5 and have the RAIDs automount after a reboot. For some reason, only one of the RAIDs */dev/md0* is persistent between boots. The remaining three RAIDs (*md1,md2,md3*) all disappear after a reboot.

I build the RAIDs using:

```
$ sudo mdadm --create --chunk 4096 --verbose /dev/md0 --level=stripe \
   --raid-devices=2 /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/nvme1n1

$ sudo mdadm --create --chunk 4096 --verbose /dev/md1 --level=stripe \
   --raid-devices=2 /dev/nvme2n1 /dev/nvme3n1

$ sudo mdadm --create --chunk 4096 --verbose /dev/md2 --level=stripe \
   --raid-devices=2 /dev/nvme4n1 /dev/nvme5n1

$ sudo mdadm --create --chunk 4096 --verbose /dev/md3 --level=stripe \
   --raid-devices=2 /dev/nvme6n1 /dev/nvme7n1
```

Then I update the `/etc/mdadm.conf` file using:

```
$ mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm.conf
```

Finally after mounting the drives to their appropriate directory and adding them to `/etc/fstab` I rebuilt the initramfs image using `dracut`:

```
$ sudo dracut --force --mdadmconf
```

After running `dracut`, I reboot the system and `/dev/md0` is there but the other RAIDs are not, so I did some investigating and it seems like `/etc/mdadm.conf` is not being included in the initramfs, so I repeated all of the previous steps, except for the `dracut` command I manually added what seemed to be missing using:

```
$ sudo dracut --force --include /etc/mdadm.conf /etc/mdadm.conf \
   --add="mdraid" --mdadmconf`
```

After running the command, I see that `/etc/mdadm.conf` and `/usr/sbin/mdadm` are included in the initramfs using:

```
$ sudo lsinitrd /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img
```

What am I missing?

**Edit 1**
I've added mdadm --assemble --scan to /etc/rc.local and tried running it from the command line once the system has booted, but md1, md2, and md3 still are not found. As before, md0 is found at boot.

I have a separate OS disk, so I am not booting from md0

Comment: Are the partitions marked linux raid? (type fd)

Comment: Looking at this it would seem to be the case that you're suppose to bring up the rest yourself - https://superuser.com/questions/801826/new-mdadm-raid-vanish-after-reboot/803182. The A'er you received is basically telling you this, but not telling you how. You could put `mdadm --assemble --scan` in `rc.local` to see if it forces them to come up. I'd suspect you could put this into systemd as well.

Comment: See this thread - https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=54901.

Answer (score 1):

The initrd only creates the RAID array needed for root and swap. Run this from the main system (after initrd changes to the real root)

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please give at least a reason. Regarding `sudo`, I didn't mean to run it from the command line as an unprivileged user, but from a script that runs as root.